# Where to purchase Mag Stock?

Tags: analog, film, stock

Howdy,

Question says it all. I'm looking to learn how to edit analog audio on my professor's Moviola, but first I need to track down some 35mm magnetic film. A few searches on Google aren't turning up much beyond historical articles. Any leads would be appreciated.

~Cheers
Miles

Answer (score 2):

I just gave a few calls to some houses I used to buy mag stock from.  None of them seems to carry it anymore.  I feel old now.

I did locate a couple of potential leads, albeit in Australia, so shipping for something as heavy as 35mm mag would probably be vicious.

Sound & Vision AU: http://www.sound-vision.com.au/products/audio_data.html

Steadi Systems: http://www.steadisystems.com/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this, Tyler. These are some great leads!

Comment: Glad I could help!